# How to reverse iterate output from subprocess in python?

Tags: python

I have a python code which iterates logs from journalctl as below, currently it print

log 1
log 2
log 3

but what I want is

log 3
log 2
log 1

How can I do this

```
import sys
import subprocess
import select
from re import search

substring = "Modem works in"

args = ['journalctl', '--lines', '100', '|', 'tail', '-n','100']
#, '_SYSTEMD_UNIT=myservice.service']

for line in subprocess.check_output(args, shell=True, universal_newlines=True).split('\n'):
    print(line)
    if search(substring, line):
        print(line)
```

Comment: if `myList=[1,2,3,4]` then `myList[::-1]` is `[4,3,2,1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many different ways of doing this. Here are two:

```py
for line in reversed(subprocess.check_output(args, shell=True, universal_newlines=True).split('\n')):
...
```

and

```py
for line in subprocess.check_output(args, shell=True, universal_newlines=True).split('\n')[::-1]:
...
```

Answer (score 1):

One other way can be

```
log_list=[]
for line in subprocess.check_output(args, shell=True, universal_newlines=True).split('\n'):
    log_list.append(line)
    print(line)
    if search(substring, line):
        log_list.append(line)
        print(line)

print(" ".join(log_list.reverse()))
```

Answer (score 1):

your_list = [1,2,3,4]

1. using **range** method:

   `print( [i for i in range(10,1,-1)] )`
2. **reversed** method:

   `print([i for i in reversed( your_list )])`
3. extended **slicing** list

   `print( your_list[::-1] )`

All of them will print:

```
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```